# Is there a way to get the number of cpu (sockets）installed in the system with windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Not the cpu logical cores, but cpu sockets? It seems that wmi provided such functionalities, but it is slow, is there any efficient c/c++ way to get this info at runtime?

Comment: Have a look here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2008/08/05/How-to-get-physical-CPU-count-on-a-server.aspx

Comment: By "sockets" do you mean physical CPUs? Or do you mean the actual sockets on the motherboard? (If a motherboard has two sockets but only one of them has a CPU, are you looking for the number one or two?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i mean the number of physical CPUs (not core)

Comment: Take a look at this page should be able to guide you to the correct objects to be referencing. Sorry can't help with c/c++ side of things. Shows processors, logical processors and cores for each cpu: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The docs on [NUMA support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363804(v=vs.85).aspx) might be what you're after.

Comment: `GetLogicalProcessorInformation` gives you the mapping between logical processors and physical cores.

Answer (score 3):

you will find the number of sockets using C++. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GLPI)(
    PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION,
    PDWORD);


// Helper function to count set bits in the processor mask.
DWORD CountSetBits(ULONG_PTR bitMask)
{
    DWORD LSHIFT = sizeof(ULONG_PTR) * 8 - 1;
    DWORD bitSetCount = 0;
    ULONG_PTR bitTest = (ULONG_PTR)1 << LSHIFT;
    DWORD i;

    for (i = 0; i <= LSHIFT; ++i)
    {
        bitSetCount += ((bitMask & bitTest) ? 1 : 0);
        bitTest /= 2;
    }

    return bitSetCount;
}

int _cdecl _tmain ()
{
    LPFN_GLPI glpi;
    BOOL done = FALSE;
    PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION buffer = NULL;
    PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION ptr = NULL;
    DWORD returnLength = 0;
    DWORD logicalProcessorCount = 0;
    DWORD numaNodeCount = 0;
    DWORD processorCoreCount = 0;
    DWORD processorL1CacheCount = 0;
    DWORD processorL2CacheCount = 0;
    DWORD processorL3CacheCount = 0;
    DWORD processorPackageCount = 0;
    DWORD byteOffset = 0;
    PCACHE_DESCRIPTOR Cache;

    glpi = (LPFN_GLPI) GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),
            "GetLogicalProcessorInformation");
    if (NULL == glpi)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nGetLogicalProcessorInformation is not supported.\n"));
        return (1);
    }

    while (!done)
    {
        DWORD rc = glpi(buffer, &returnLength);

        if (FALSE == rc)
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                if (buffer)
                    free(buffer);

                buffer = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION)malloc(
                            returnLength);

                if (NULL == buffer)
                {
                    _tprintf(TEXT("\nError: Allocation failure\n"));
                    return (2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("\nError %d\n"), GetLastError());
                return (3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            done = TRUE;
        }
    }

    ptr = buffer;

    while (byteOffset + sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION) <= returnLength)
    {
        switch (ptr->Relationship)
        {
        case RelationNumaNode:
            // Non-NUMA systems report a single record of this type.
            numaNodeCount++;
            break;

        case RelationProcessorCore:
            processorCoreCount++;

            // A hyperthreaded core supplies more than one logical processor.
            logicalProcessorCount += CountSetBits(ptr->ProcessorMask);
            break;

        case RelationCache:
            // Cache data is in ptr->Cache, one CACHE_DESCRIPTOR structure for each cache.
            Cache = &ptr->Cache;
            if (Cache->Level == 1)
            {
                processorL1CacheCount++;
            }
            else if (Cache->Level == 2)
            {
                processorL2CacheCount++;
            }
            else if (Cache->Level == 3)
            {
                processorL3CacheCount++;
            }
            break;

        case RelationProcessorPackage:
            // Logical processors share a physical package.
            processorPackageCount++;
            break;

        default:
            _tprintf(TEXT("\nError: Unsupported LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP value.\n"));
            break;
        }
        byteOffset += sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION);
        ptr++;
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("\nGetLogicalProcessorInformation results:\n"));
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of NUMA nodes: %d\n"),
            numaNodeCount);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of physical processor sockets: %d\n"),
            processorPackageCount);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of processor cores: %d\n"),
            processorCoreCount);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of logical processors: %d\n"),
            logicalProcessorCount);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Number of processor L1/L2/L3 caches: %d/%d/%d\n"),
            processorL1CacheCount,
            processorL2CacheCount,
            processorL3CacheCount);

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```